# SonarLint V3: Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable for List interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

My question is very similar to [this](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/squid-S1948-False-positives-td5034885.html) except that this issue I have encountered in SonarLint V3 (squid:S1948).

My code is :

```
public class Page<T> implements Serializable {

    Summary summary;
    List<T> elements;

    public Page() {
        summary = new Summary();
    }

    public List<T> getItemsReceived() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setItemsReceived(List<T> list) {
        this.elements = list;
    }

    public Summary getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(Summary summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

}
```

The Summary Object implements serializable.

```
public class Summary implements Serializable {

    int offset;
    int limit;
    long totalElements;

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public void setOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public long getTotalNumberOfElements() {
        return totalElements;
    }

    public void setTotalNumberOfElements(long totalNumberOfElements) {
        this.totalElements = totalNumberOfElements;

    }

}
```

Now, If I replace List by ArrayList , then another warning in SonarLint arises that we should be using interface instead of implementation classes.

I think this might be resolved in SonarQube but for SonarLint I don't know.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: SonarQube and SonarLint share the analyzer responsible for detecting issues in Java code https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/java.html, so you should see the same issues if you use same version of SonarJava in both tools. Now concerning your code, in which file and what line is issue raised?

Comment: The Page class. SonarLint reports that List<T> is not serializable and hence should be. If I replace it by ArrayList, then it reports that I should use interface. In both ways I am getting this. My question : This was a bug in `SonarQube` few years earlier and since I am using latest version of `SonarLint` ,  why is this still comming in intellij ?

Comment: This is not the same issue as the one you linked. See my answer.

Comment: Strict answer to the question: add `// NOSONAR` to hide the warning. (However `Page<T extends Serializable>` is also necessary, as mentioned by @TiborBlenessy.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SonarLint is right. The problem is that there is no guarantee that `elements` field is serializable. You need to add type bound on `T` type like this

```
public class Page<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {}
```

This way the list will be serializable if implementation chosen for it is serializable (which is true for standard collection types in Java).