# SonarQube requires field to be either serializable or transient

Tags: java, spring, serialization

I created a class `SuperUser` that extends `User` class from Spring Security(`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`)

```
class SuperUser extends User implements UserDetails {

    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

`User` class is serializable because it implements `UserDetails` that extends `Serializable`. Therefore my `SuperUser` class needs to be serializable too.

I want my `SuperUser` to have a set of roles.
I've created a property `roles` of type `java.util.Set` and started to get critical SonarQube complaints.

I get the following warning: Make "roles" transient or serializable. Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable.

Is it really critical if all concrete implementations of `Set` used in my application implement `Serializable` interface?

Is there any practice to deal with this kind of warning?

(I wouldn't like to change the roles variable type to concrete implementation.)

Comment: Is `Role` serializable?

Comment: @TiborBlenessy, yes

Comment: Do you have a rule key which is reporting the issue? If it's SonarJava rule (starting with `squid`) , which version do you use?

Comment: @TiborBlenessy, I've just checked that making `Role` serializable solved the problem. I didn't notice that this problem disappeared from report. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarLint V3: Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable for List interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279371/sonarlint-v3-fields-in-a-serializable-class-should-either-be-transient-or-ser)

Comment: Happy to help. In fact there was already same question, so I marked this one as duplicate.