# Non entity variables: Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarlint

Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable is possible to fix any entity/class is used in another class, but it occurs when List/ Map is declared in a dto class which can't be even made as transient as well. please let me know how to fix this.

Ex:

```
public class CustomMetadataDTO implements Serializable {

private UUID id;

private Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();

private UUID fieldGroupId;

private Integer order;


public CustomMetadataDTO(Map<String, Object> metadata, Integer order) {
    this.metadata = metadata;
    this.order = order;
}

public CustomMetadataDTO() {
}}
```

for below line I get the sonarqube issue as critical

```
private Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632332/fields-in-a-serializable-class-should-either-be-transient-or-serializable)

Comment: The objects stored in the map aren't serializable, you should at least set the type instead of Object to Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is serializable but Map is not as it does not implement Serializable interface. You can try using HashMap itself while declaring (not recommended).

```
private HashMap<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
```